# Same solution displays different links on different servers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, javascript, sharepoint-server

I created a farm solution. One of the webparts retrieves data from internal rootsite.

```
<script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the test server (Windows 2012), it works well.

But in the production server (Windows 2008), these links add server name (`http`) automatically.

```
<script src="http://100ar200:80/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Because our SharePoint site uses `https://` it always display an error message

> Only secure content is displayed

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the double slash // to tell the browser to accept either http or https. This should do the trick.

```
//Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a real probability the problem comes from a mis-configured AAM. If you browse your site with https:// but https is not registered in AAM (or is registered as an internal URL of the default zone), then all links in the page will be replaces by SharePoint by the public URL of the default zone.

Check your AMM (in Central Administration, "Application management", select your Web app and then "Alternate Access Mappings" from the ribbon), and be sure your https:// URL is set as a public URL.

Answer (score 0):

we retract then solution and redeploy the solution. 
Then, it works well.

We think that we had changed the link to`https`after we deploy the solution in production server. So this solution does not update with the link https.